# Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto en @foreach (var item in Model)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, foreach, null

espero me puedan ayudar soy novata, estoy realizando una aplicación web con ASP.net MVC pero no puedo encontrar el error que origina esta excepción,  este es mi código.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Les explico un poco, estoy tratando de mostrar una lista de una pantalla parcial.

Mi vista principal

```
@model Entity.CovidCE

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Registro";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Pmedico.cshtml";
}

  <div class="col-md-6">
       @Html.Partial("GetPruebaCovid")
  </div>
```

Mi vista parcial (que contiene la lista)

```
@model IEnumerable<Entity.covid>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.covid_id)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.covid_paci_id)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.covid_fecha)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.covid_tipo)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.covid_resultado)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.covid_condicion)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.covid_frecuencia)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.covid_id)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.covid_paci_id)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.covid_fecha)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.covid_tipo)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.covid_resultado)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.covid_condicion)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.covid_frecuencia)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

   </table>
```

He estado investigando, y lo que encuentro es que esta tratando de acceder a un objeto nulo. Mi duda es que cuando ejecuto la vista parcial si me muestra la lista sin ningún error, y cuando llamo la vista parcial desde mi vista principal me lanza esta excepción.

Les agradecería si me pudieras ayudar.

Comment: Creo que tienes que pasarle el modelo a la vista parcial desde la vista principal, de lo contrario la vista parcial queda sin modelo. [La documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.partialextensions.partial?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_Html_PartialExtensions_Partial_System_Web_Mvc_HtmlHelper_System_String_System_Object_) explica que es posible pasar el modelo como segundo argumento de tipo `object` en `@Html.Partial`.

Comment: Y como podría pasarle el modelo a la vista parcial? En la misma vista, o en el controlador.

Answer (score 0):

La vista parcial debe recibir un modelo `IEnumerable<Entity.covid>` que deberías pasárselo cuando haces la llamada a `@Html.Partial`.

Para ello necesitarás que la vista principal tenga acceso a esa información. Si no está ya, podrías añadir una nueva propiedad al modelo `CovidCE`.

De esta forma el modelo `CovidCE` tendría una nueva propiedad:

```
public IEnumerable<Entity.covid> ListOfCovids { get; set; }
```

Los datos de esta propiedad deberías cargarlos en tu controlador. De esta forma al llamar a la vista parcial el pasarías el valor de esta propiedad como modelo:

```
@Html.Partial("GetPruebaCovid", Model.ListOfCovids)
```